# Download the file from a remote SFTP server in Node.js + Vue.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my **Vue.js** application I need to download `.csv` file from a remote `SFTP` server.

I am tring to use [ssh2-sftp-client](https://github.com/jyu213/ssh2-sftp-client) **Node.js** library to download the file.

After installation I have next error:

```
This dependency was not found:

* dns in ./node_modules/ssh2/lib/client.js

To install it, you can run: npm install --save dns
```

I installed the missing dependencies with the following command:

```
npm install --save dns
```

After that step I see other error:

```
 warning  in ./node_modules/defaultable/defaultable.js

49:13-31 Critical dependency: the request of a dependency is an expression
```

First question is how to set up the library correctly?

---

**EDIT**

Code inside Vue.js component:

```
getFile (fileName) {
    axios.post('http://localhost:3010/csv', {file_name: fileName}, {headers: {'Authorization': this.token}}).then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        this.showAlert('You download file successfully.', 'is-success', 'is-top')
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error)
        this.showAlert(error, 'is-danger', 'is-bottom')
    })
}
```

**app.js:**

```
const express = require('express');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const csvRouter = require('./server/routes/csv')

const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'dist')));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(cookieParser());

app.use('/csv', csvRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

**routers/csv.js:**

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()

const csvControllers = require('../controllers/csv')

router.get('/', csvControllers.getFile)

module.exports = router
```

**controllers/csv.js:**

```
const request = require('request')
const queryString = require('query-string')
let Client = require('ssh2-sftp-client')
let sftp = new Client()

const config = require('../config')

exports.getFile = (req, res) => {
  console.log(req)  // In console I don't notice nothing.
  let data = {
    file_name: req.query.file_name
  }
  let options = {
    method: 'port',
    json: true,
    header: {'Authorization': req.header.token},
    url: `http://localhost:3010/csv?` + queryString.stringify(data)
  }
  request(options, (error, response) => {
    console.log('Message')  // In console I don't notice nothing.
    if (response) {
      sftp.connect(config.sftpServer).then(() => {
        return sftp.get('/reports/' + data.file_name)
      }).then((chunk) => {
        console.log(chunk)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
      })
    } else {
      response.status(500).send(error)
    }
  })
}
```

**ERROR:**

```
Error: Request failed with status code 404
    at FtD3.t.exports (createError.js:16)
    at t.exports (settle.js:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.f.(:3010/anonymous function) (http://localhost:3010/static/js/vendor.1dc24385e2ad03071ff8.js:1312:88758)
```

It seems like url address don't correct cause error is 404 in browser. I check url address several times but did't notice something wrong. What I miss?

Comment: Are you trying to use this module in client side code? Because I believe it's meant to be used as server-side (node) only.

Answer (score 0):

Vue.js runs in the browser. You can't use modules that depend on features provided by Node.js which are not available in browsers.

There is no way to use SSH directly from a browser.

Comment: I am new in that stack and little bit confused about interaction between vue.js and node.js. Lets say user click some button. After that we start node.js controller which connect to remote SFTP server and get csv file. Where node.js store that file? What happens next?

Comment: "I am new in that stack and little bit confused about interaction between vue.js and node.js." — Vue.js is a library for SPAs which runs in the browser. Node.js is a tool to run JavaScript without using a browser.

Comment: "Lets say user click some button. After that we start node.js controller" — You can't per se. You could write an HTTP server using Node.js, and make an HTTP request from the browser to the HTTP server and have it respond in some way.

Comment: "Where node.js store that file?" — Wherever you tell it to store it.

Comment: Hello! Can you check my post again please. I add some information. I make HTTP server in Node.js as you adviced. It return me `Error: Request failed with status code 404`. What I miss? I add to post my current code.